# How to add Mediatr to DryIoc

Tags: c#, mediatr, dryioc

I am currently trying to port a Mediatr Pipeline (`Mediatr 7.0.0`) implementation to use a `DryIoc` `Container` (`v. 4.0.5`). I Used the following implementation I had from `DryIoC` version `3.0.2`:

```
private static void ConfigureMediatr(this Container container)
{
    container.RegisterDelegate<ServiceFactory>(r => r.Resolve);
    container.RegisterMany(new[] { typeof(IMediator).GetAssembly()}, Registrator.Interfaces);
    container.RegisterMany(typeof(CopyManualsHandler).GetAssembly().GetTypes().Where(t => t.IsMediatorHandler())); //Use this to only Get Mediator Handlers.

    container.Register(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(RequestPreProcessorBehavior<,>), ifAlreadyRegistered: IfAlreadyRegistered.AppendNewImplementation);
    container.Register(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(RequestPostProcessorBehavior<,>), ifAlreadyRegistered: IfAlreadyRegistered.AppendNewImplementation);
}
```

The implementation works on `3.0.2` fine and my pipeline seems fine as well (if I just change the nuget package from `4.0.5` to `3.0.2` everything works fine). However on `4.0.5` I receive the exception:

```
System.TypeInitializationException
  HResult=0x80131534
  Message=The type initializer for 'DryIoc.OpenGenericTypeKey' threw an exception.
  Source=Program.Manuals
  StackTrace:
   at DryIoc.OpenGenericTypeKey..ctor(Type requiredServiceType, Object serviceKey) in Container.cs:line 2255
   at DryIoc.WrappersSupport.<>c__DisplayClass12_0.<GetArrayExpression>b__6(KV`2 f) in Container.cs:line 3656
   at ImTools.ArrayTools.Map[T,R](T[] source, Func`2 map) in ImTools.cs:line 569
   at ImTools.ArrayTools.Map[T,R](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 map) in ImTools.cs:line 605
   at DryIoc.WrappersSupport.GetArrayExpression(Request request) in Container.cs:line 3655
   at DryIoc.ExpressionFactory.CreateExpressionOrDefault(Request request) in Container.cs:line 9062
   at DryIoc.Factory.GetExpressionOrDefault(Request request) in Container.cs:line 7865
   at DryIoc.Container.ResolveAndCacheFactoryDelegate(Type serviceType, IfUnresolved ifUnresolved) in Container.cs:line 269
   at DryIoc.Container.DryIoc.IResolver.Resolve(Type serviceType, IfUnresolved ifUnresolved) in Container.cs:line 230
   at DryIoc.Resolver.Resolve(IResolver resolver, Type serviceType) in Container.cs:line 5880
   at MediatR.ServiceFactoryExtensions.GetInstances[T](ServiceFactory factory)
   at MediatR.Internal.RequestHandlerWrapperImpl`2.Handle(IRequest`1 request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, ServiceFactory serviceFactory)
   at MediatR.Mediator.Send[TResponse](IRequest`1 request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at GOM.PCMF.Manuals.ViewModels.ButtonViewModel.<Copy>d__20.MoveNext() in ButtonViewModel.cs:line 76
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__6_0(Object state) in f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\runtime\compilerservices\AsyncMethodBuilder.cs:line 1018
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
   at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.CallbackWrapper(Object obj)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx) in f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\threading\executioncontext.cs:line 954
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx) in f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\threading\executioncontext.cs:line 901
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state) in f:\dd\ndp\clr\src\BCL\system\threading\executioncontext.cs:line 890
   at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(CulturePreservingExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run()
   at Program.Manuals.App.Main()

Inner Exception 1:
ContainerException: Unable to find a single constructor in Type OpenGenericTypeKey (including non-public=False)
```

(Removed the Full Filepath to some Items in the Stacktrace. However no `DryIoC` class was edited therefore the line numbers should be correct).

I tried to fix the issue using [this `DryIoC` example](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/blob/master/samples/MediatR.Examples.DryIoc/Program.cs).
However this won't work for me because the `Container` tries to get to many `Types` registered. Thats why I switched to this line:
    container.RegisterMany(typeof(CopyManualsHandler).GetAssembly().GetTypes().Where(t => t.IsMediatorHandler()));

which utilizes this Method to find all RequestHandlers:

```
public static bool IsMediatorHandler(this Type arg)
        {
            return arg.GetInterfaces()
                .Where(i => i.Name.StartsWith("IRequestHandler"))
                .Any();
        }
```

The Question now: Am I doing something wrong while registering the types? Or could this be a bug coming from `DryIoc`?

Comment: Are you using DryIoc or DryIoc.dll package?

Comment: I am using DryIoc installed by nuget Package. I am getting a Folder with the DryIoc Classes into my application. There is (as far as I know) no extra DryIoc.dll found in my Output folder.

Comment: If that helps: The Mediatr Pipeline and all its classes live in a class library. The calling Code that constructs the Container from DryIoc is a wpf application.

Comment: Try DryIoc.dll or DryIoc.Internal packages.

Comment: I'll try it on monday. Giving you feedback then. Thanks for helping and looking into it.

Comment: Tried it a second ago and using the DryIoc.dll seems to work fine (I am hitting my Mediatr Handler now). Thank you for the help @dadhi. Could you elaborate why the DryIoc.dll works and the DryIoc source is not working even though they have the same version number?

Comment: Gave a full answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the *DryIoc* source package and registering its public types as well.

You need to either filter out `DryIoc` namespace in `RegisterMany` calls, or use *DryIoc.Internal* or *DryIoc.dll* packages.

Comment: Thanks for the Clarification. That explains the (for me at least) weird error regarding DryIoc Types.

Comment: Btw, DryIoc v4 has its own MediatR-like abstractions in `DryIoc.Messages` namespace

Comment: The DryIoc.Messages docs with the live example are here: https://github.com/dadhi/DryIoc/blob/master/docs/DryIoc.Docs/DryIoc.Messages.md